# Why is my header component defined but never used in my test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

Im trying to get a react testing library test going but having lots of issues

```js
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import {render, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react'

test("Renders's the header and required inputs", () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Header/>);
  const Header = component.getByTestId ('header');
  expect(Header.textContent).toBe("Shipping Label")
})
```

The component exports Header.

Comment: Maybe it's confused because you have both a global `import Header from './Header'` **and** a second `const Header = component.getByTestId ('header');` that is scoped to the anonymous function in your test? Which `Header` are you exporting?

Comment: Define "lots of issues."

Comment: I was following the syntax pretty directly from this tuturial about header testing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLSSRtnNY0g

Comment: saying component is not defined

Comment: also the header declared but not being read

Comment: gettestbyid also being affected

Comment: `getByTestId` is a function of `screen` from testing-library IIRC, not something returned by `render`. You might want to also check out the [@testing-library/react docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/). It's difficult to tell if your `<Header>` component is being imported correctly, but it does complicate things when you create a *new* `Header` when you try to access whatever `component` is (don't see that anywhere in the code). I'd consider taking a brief step back to learn about testing-library before going much further.

Comment: @DaveNewton this code is directly from a tutorial so its hard to get it going without having a very basic test like this work.

Comment: I’m not sure what to tell you—I would look at the docs or a another tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header'
import {render} from '@testing-library/react'

test("Renders's the header and required inputs", () => {
 const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(<Header />);
  expect(getByTestId("header")).toBeTruthy();
  expect(getByText("Shipping Label")).toBeTruthy();
})
```

Try something like this, I think you are trying to use "component" from enzyme or such, and it's not defined.

Take a look at the [testing library cheat sheet](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet/)

Comment: Oh this is great syntax for testing components with Jest / React Testing Library

Answer (score 0):

You will need to import React at the top of the file which may cause issues if you don't with rendering things.

```
import React from "react";
```

Comment: Sorry that didnt get added but its in the test will add now